# In fallout 4 is the East Boston Police Station Haunted?

Tags: fallout-4

I was playing *Fallout 4* exploring and I decided to check out a collapsed building I saw. I went outside and found out it was the East Boston Police Station. I read the logs and then jumped off and went downstairs to the cells where I saw a cell door open by itself and after this I heard really creepy background music, but I'm usually not listening to the game so that might just be the normal music. Is this place haunted?

Xbox One name: TheBlazePhase, I recorded what happened and set it as my showcase.

Comment: Some doors seem to open by themselves but sometimes it might just be your follower as well if they're nearby. As for this particular case I don't know. Were there any hints in the logs you read?

Answer (score 1):

After watching the video I'm certain it was just your follower walking past the cell which caused it to open. Also the creepy background music seemed to already be playing, and wasn't triggered by the door opening.